# WorksheetFunction.Countif Line not reading my Address function

Tags: vba, function, range

I am trying to have a macros that will pull numbers no matter where they are pasted. I am using index match to pull these from an input. I have been successful in finding the "Addresses" for what I am looking for. How do I get functions to reference the Address in the Cells and not the Cells themselves?

It is right on the tip of my tongue and it is maddening. When I put

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(Indirect(Address(5,9,True,"Sheet2")), Range("C1").Value)>0= True Then
```

There is a function error. When I put in

```
Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(Variable.Address(Extrenal:=True), Range("C1").Value)>0= True Then
```

There is a mismatch error

I have tried Indirect(address()) but when I plug this into Index match it says that there is an error. `Index(indirect(address()),Match(Ref,Indirect(Address),0))`

I have also been trying to use the address in a countif statement.

```
If Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(Indirect(Address(5,9,True,"Sheet2")), Range("C1").Value)>0= True Then...
```

Also,

```
(Index(indirect(address()),Match(Ref,Indirect(Address),0))
```

I am getting as mentioned a mismatch error and a function error. I will take any method to fix either of these.

Comment: Right off the bat, you misspelled external

Comment: The first criterion in the `Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif` is a range not a string address.

Comment: you want `If Application.WorksheetFunction.Countif(Variable, Range("C1").Value)>0 Then`  Where `Variable` is a range.

Comment: Hi, it is saying Mismatch when I try-          Variable as Range                                                                             Set Variable = Variable.Address(External:=True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you all for your input. This is what I came up with.`Dim SKU as Range;Dim SKUR as Range;Dim SKU1 as String;Dim Variable as String;Dim VariableR as Range;Set SKU = Worksheets("Sheets1").Range("A:AC").Find("Number");Set SKUR =SKU.EntireColumn;Variable - SKUR.Address(External:=True);SetVariableR=Range(Variable);SKU1=Application.WorksheetFunction.IfError(Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(VariableR,(Application.WorksheetFunction.Match((Range("C1").Value),VariableR,0)),0);Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("C5").Value = SKU1`

Again, this is what I came up for using index match in VBA using an address range I found.Some reason it won't let me post it with the spaces so I am using semi colons to separate lines, please take them out when using this.